# count() return 0 after use skip and take in laravel ORM

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to use count() and skip() in seperate laravel ORM.

But in this special case count() dosn't work true and return 0 value.

this is my code, in two case when i use:

```
        $query  = Order::where('status',0)->orderBy('id','DESC');
        $orders = $query->skip(0)->take(6)->get()->toArray();
        echo    $query->count();//50
```

its ok but when i use this:

```
        $query  = Order::where('status',0)->orderBy('id','DESC');
        $orders = $query->skip(6)->take(6)->get()->toArray();
        echo    $query->count();//0
```

it return 0 value but should return 50. what's problem ?

Comment: which laravel version?

Comment: Can you enable query log and post the query on both cases? (Put `DB::connection()->enableQueryLog()` before the query and `dd(DB::getQueryLog());` after it)

Comment: @ÖmerYilmaz i use version 7.0

Answer (score 1):

You are counting on the query object directly, try it like this it will work.

```
$query  = Order::where('status',0)->orderBy('id','DESC');
// to get 50 rows
$orders = $query->skip(6)->take(50)->get();
// $ordArr = $orders->toArray();
echo $orders->count();
```

Comment: this will be return 6 absolutely !

Comment: Change ```->take(6)``` to ```->take(50)``` it will get 50 rows skipping 6.
I updated the answer.